# DataGridView Custom Sort in WinForm

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview

My DataGridView control currently sorts using the Sort property of the bound data, but it isn't doing what I want it to do.

I have a column called `Employee` that is displayed as "Firstname Lastname".

When I sort by `Employee`, Amy Z_Lastname is listed before John A_Lastname, meaning I would prefer to sort by last names.

I *could* break the Employee string up into 3 parts, include those in the DataTable, and set the sort to "Lastname, Firstname", then hide the Lastname and Firstname columns.

I'd *rather* learn how to override the default IComparer (or whatever it uses) to provide instructions on how to sort the way I want (the answer I'd prefer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Custom sorting in the DataGridView](http://www.teamjohnston.net/blogs/jesse/post/2006/12/10/Custom-sorting-in-the-DataGridView.aspx)

> The DataGridView knows nothing of this
>   ranking, of course.  The default
>   sorting scenario (automatic sorting
>   for a data-bound column) of invoking
>   DataGridView.Sort() via a column
>   header mouse click simply delegates to
>   the IBindingList implementation of
>   ApplySort() in the list you've bound
>   to the grid.  Normally, this list
>   would be a DataView.  Using my
>   ObjectListView  implementation, this
>   would be a view of a list of arbitrary
>   business objects.  Either way, you end
>   up comparing the properties of the
>   items in the list using the
>   IComparable implementation of the
>   property type.
>
> **Details**
>
> The PropertyComparers property exposes
>   a PropertyComparersCollection, which
>   is a dictionary of property name keys
>   and IComparer values.  You can replace
>   the IComparer for a property by using
>   the PropertyComparersCollection.Add()
>   method or the indexer (e.g.
>   view.PropertyComparers["PropName"] =
>   myComparer).  To revert to the default
>   IComparable sorting, use the
>   PropertyComparersCollection.Remove()
>   method or set the IComparer value to
>   null via the indexer.
>
> If an IComparer is added to the
>   PropertyComparers collection, it will
>   be used for all subsequent sorts until
>   it is removed from the collection or
>   it is replaced with another IComparer.
>   If the ObjectListView is already
>   sorted when an IComparer is added to
>   or removed from PropertyComparers, the
>   view will automatically be re-sorted.
>
> If you want to change multiple
>   property comparers after the view is
>   sorted, you can use the ObjectListView
>   BeginUpdate() and EndUpdate() methods
>   to suppress the ListChanged and Sort
>   events until all of the IComparers
>   have been changed.  This prevents
>   multiple refreshes of the
>   DataGridView.  If the ObjectListView
>   is not sorted at the time IComparers
>   are added or removed, no automatic
>   re-sorting is done.
>
> Note that when sorting on multiple
>   columns, a custom IComparer can be
>   used with one sort property, and the
>   default IComparable sort on another.

e.g:

```
private void radioButtonSortProgram_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

    if (this.radioButtonSortProgramAlpha.Checked)

        this.view.PropertyComparers["Program"] = new CustomerProgramComparerAlpha();

    else if (this.radioButtonSortProgramRank.Checked)

        this.view.PropertyComparers["Program"] = new CustomerProgramComparerRank();

    else

        this.view.PropertyComparers.Remove("Program");

}
```

Comment: Please write a brief digest of the article, with code, in case of link rot.  Looks like you implement IComparable, and either living with virtual mode, or using a custom list view implementation.

Comment: I've sent the author a question. His solution was to use the ObjectListView, but he never defines it.

Comment: @jp2code: You may want to look at sorting before it reaches the client instead. I imagine you'll only display a certain size of results at a time (paging) so the cost really isn't that high.

Comment: I've marked this as the answer, but I won't be able to modify my application to use this ObjectListView control for a while. If a better answer comes along before I've had a chance to implement OLV, I will change my answer. Thanks.